# AngularJS - Pass an array of objects to MVC Controller via $http

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, service, controller

I'm wondering a long time and I can't find a solution, maybe someone of you resolved a similar problem.

Let's say we want to pass and **array of objects** via $http service to the MVC Controller.
This array is created in angular so I don't know the proper type (just var).
**The problem is I don't know what type of parameter should be in MVC function**

AngularJS Controller

```
$scope.DoSth = function (){
    var data = [{
        Id: "1",
        Value: "apple"
    },
    {
        Id: "2",
        Value: "banana"
    }];
};

//DoSthService injected into angular controller

DoSthService.doSth(data)
    .success(function(result){
        //sth with success result
    })
    .error(function(result){
        //sth with error result
    });
```

AngularJS Service:

```
this.doSth = function(data){
    var response = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "Home/DoSth",
        data: data
        //or data: JSON.stringify(data) ??
        });
    return response;
};
```

MVC Controller:

```
public string DoSth(**what type here?** data)
{
    //do sth and return string
}
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: You need something like jackson to map json to a pojo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class

```
public class  MyClass
{
  public int Id { get; set;}
  public string Value { get; set;}
}
```

use the list in your method

```
public string DoSth(List<MyClass> data)
{
    //access your data
    //data[0].Id,data[0].Value or by any other way
}
```

No need to change any of your js code

Comment: No problem. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to put model here.

public string DoSth(FruitModel  data)
{
    //do sth and return string
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Karthik M R's answer was more precise

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken you can do this with a stringtype (if JSON is sent)

```
public string DoSth(string data)
{
    //do sth and return string
}
```

Don't forget to add this header in your AJAX request:

```
headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

Also stringify it, like:

```
data: JSON.stringify(data)
```

If you did it right your AJAX request should look like this:

```
this.doSth = function(data){
    var response = $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'Home/DoSth',
            headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(data)
        });
    return response;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I checked it but I still received null object, don't know why.